# On update trigger in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, sql-update

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comenzi` (
  `idcomanda` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iduser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idprodus` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numepiesa` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pretunit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantitate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pretftva` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valtva` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nrfactura` int(11) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `achitat` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataachitat` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcomanda`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Hey Guys,I have the table structure mentioned above and I never did triggers in MySQL, could you help me out with this one please.

I need to update the "dataachitat"column with the currentdate everytime a row has the "achitat" value set to 1

Ex. Let's say that the first  item is affected by an update script and the achitat value is set to 1, i need the "dataachitat" column of that row to be automatically set to currentdate.

Please help me out

Cheers !

Comment: So what have you tried so far? We're not here to just bang out code for you. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: You can use sqlfiddle to create examples too

Comment: here is a template we can work with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8a87

Comment: also:  what is a "dataachitat"

Comment: Use a default column value instead of a trigger.

Comment: I accidentaly pasted the wrong table sql, i updated it right now, so far i have only a solution from a PHP standpoint, but i considered it more effective in having a trigger

Comment: so, whats wrong?  What have you tried?  I mean, I already have an answer in SQL fiddle, but have you ever made a trigger before is that what you are trying to figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to perform the specified action would look something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trg_comenzi_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON comenzi
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.achitat = 1 THEN
    SET NEW.dataachitat = DATE(NOW());
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

(This is desk checked only; there could be issues with the order of the keywords; the `BEFORE UPDATE` might come after `ON comenzi`, et al.)

**NOTE:** The `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger will only be "fired" when an UPDATE statement affects a row in the table, it won't be fired when a row is inserted to the table. You'd need an equivalent `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to do the same thing on an INSERT.

**NOTE:** The `IF` statement in the trigger body checks if the value of the achitat column is 1; it doesn't check if the previous (OLD) value was something other than 1. That is, the `IF` will evaluate to TRUE whether the achitat was changed to a 1, or if it was already a 1.

If you only want the SET action to be performed if the achitat column is ***changed to*** 1 from some other value, you could do something like this:

```
  IF (NEW.achitat = 1 AND (OLD.achitat <> 1 OR OLD.achitat IS NULL)) THEN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! you have been a huge help, i'm new to stackoverflow, do i have any possiblity of rating your help ?

Comment: @Arsenelonut: If this answered your question, and you feel you don't need any further answers to your question, you could "accept" this answer.